# alter image style attribute

Tags: 9

i am trying to develop a CKEDITOR plugin to add padding/margin to images,

after looking in the documentations i have written this code :

```
const style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'img', attributes: { 'style': 'margin:100px' } } );
editor.applyStyle(style);
```

but it didn't work so i tryied :

```
const style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'image', attributes: { 'style': 'margin:100px' } } );
editor.applyStyle(style);
```

and still did not work,
i read that on drupal 9 the image is a widget and not an element so i tryied:

```
const style = new CKEDITOR.style( { type:'widget', widget: 'image' , attributes: { 'style': 'margin:100px' } } );
editor.applyStyle(style);
```

and still did not work, so i tryied :

```
const style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'p', attributes: { 'style': 'margin:100px' } } );
editor.applyStyle(style);
```

and it did work but it was added to the 'p' wraping the img so i know that the code is currect but i can't seem to add it to the img...

Answer (score 1):

Trying to create a CKEditor plugin is not as easy as it might look. I'd suggest to check the amazing module [CKEditor Templates](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_templates) (in a nutshell, you will need to extend the CKEditorPluginBase class).